# Python print error bar with only 3 values (Min, Max and the current value)

Tags: python

How to display a kind of errorbar with only 3 Values :
For example :

Max = 20
Min = 10
Current = 15

Output excepted :
[image]

The following is not working :

```
ax.errorbar([0,1], [10,20], yerr=15, fmt='o', color='black',
             ecolor='lightgray', elinewidth=3, capsize=0);
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)

y = x + 15
y_err_min = y - 5
y_err_max = y + 5

y_err = np.stack([y - y_err_min, y_err_max - y])

fig = plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=y_err)
```

[image]

---

For your specific problem, you can use the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 0
y = 15
y_err = [[5], [5]]

fig = plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=y_err, marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markeredgecolor='blue', linestyle='-', color='red', capsize=10)
```

[image]

Comment: It is not the output excepted I just want a bar starting at Min and ending at Max with a Point at Current. Like in my drawing

Comment: But this does display 2 bar and the min and max is not excepted

Comment: I just added the specific code you want.

Comment: So Yerr just substract a value to 15 and add a value to 15 : 15-5 and 15+5 ? 
Many thanks